# inserting figure

Tags: floats

I need to insert two figures horizontally in one column of a two column document.I tried the code below

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
 \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.1\linewidth}
 \centering
 \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{coffee.jpg}
 \caption{Coffee.}
 \end{subfigure}
 \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.1\linewidth}
  \centering
 \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{coffee.jpg}
 \caption{More coffee.}
 \end{subfigure}
 \caption{The same cup of coffee. Two times.}
 \label{fig:coffee}
\end{figure*}
```

I obtained the figure like this

[image]

But I need figures horizontally.How can I modify my code to get this

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Have you tried changing both instances of `\begin{subfigure}[h]{0.1\linewidth}` to `\begin{subfigure}{0.45\columnwidth}`?

Comment: change `\begin{figure}[h!]` to `\begin{figure*}[htb]` ... (note `*`)

Comment: @Zarko  - The OP has stated that both graphs must fit in a single column.

Comment: I tried \begin{figure*}[htb] but not working

Comment: I need both images should fit in a single column

Comment: @Mico, you are right! i look only in code, where i see inconsistency in use of `figure` environment. your comment solve her problem.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Output]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx, subcaption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{figure}[h]
     \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.24\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
         \caption{Coffee.}
     \end{subfigure}
     \hfill
     \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.24\textwidth}
          \centering
         \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
         \caption{More coffee.}
     \end{subfigure}
     \caption{The same cup of coffee. Two times.}
     \label{fig:coffee}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[3-6]
\end{document}
```

Comment: instead of `\begin{subfigure}[h]{0.24\textwidth}` is better to use `\begin{subfigure}[htb]{0.45\columnwidth}` as suggested @Mico in his comment. also in your code  `\centering` is superfluous in `subfigure`s.

Comment: Thank you.Now it works